# How to navigate between ContentEditable divs with arrow keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## Context

I am implementing an editor in React. For simplicity's sake, assume each paragraph in my editor is a content editable element like: `<p contentEditable>...</p>` (in reality I'm using the `react-contenteditable` library).

## Question

I would like to implement a function where if I reach the top of my block, and I press arrow up, I would focus on the block above with the caret set to closest to my original position. Likewise, when I reach the bottom and press arrow down, I would like to navigate to the block below.

See below image for an example. If I press arrow up from the position as shown, I would like the caret to move to the red position:

[image]

## My progress so far

I implemented the following event handler for `onKeyDown` to determine when a user has reached the top of the block (`getCaretCoordinates` is taken from [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-find-the-caret-inside-a-contenteditable-element-955a5ad9bf81) post):

```
// ...inside my component
handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    const caretCoordinates = getCaretCoordinates();
    const boundingRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const caretIsTopOfDiv = caretCoordinates.y <= boundingRect.y;

    if (caretIsTopOfDiv) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // trigger function to move caret
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm stuck trying to implement the rest of the logic (i.e. to focus on the block above and move the caret to the appropriate position).

Would love some advice on how I should progress.

Edit: Please see [this code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/nhusdLa0/) for my current progress.

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet with tool `<>`

Comment: Hi, please see: https://jsfiddle.net/nhusdLa0/

Comment: Hi @DonovanSo did you manage to solve it? I'm trying to do the exact same thing at the moment.